# my call on an array returns nothing with prisma and next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma

while doing this call, in next.js, followerUsers is returning empty, while i know that there are values in it.

I know that followerIds isn't empty and has the good entry for the code to work, so i suppose that the "in" in my last calls is the problem.

In prisma doc, it is not definitely said that i can use it like that, but it should be ok, and it's the only way i have find to find multiple things with an array with prisma.

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { getServerAuthSession } from "~/server/auth";
import { prisma } from "~/server/db/prisma";

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  const { searchParams } = new URL(request.url);
  const username = searchParams.get("username");
  console.log("username", username);

  try {
    const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: {
        username,
      },
    });
    console.log("user", user);

    const userId: string = user?.id;

    const followers = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: userId,
      },
      include: {
        followers: true,
      },
    });
    console.log("followers", followers);

    const followerIds = followers?.followers.map((follower) => follower.id);
    console.log("followerIds", followerIds);

    const followerUsers = await prisma.user.findMany({
      where: {
        id: {
          in: followerIds,
        },
      },
    });

    console.log("followerUsers", followerUsers);

    return NextResponse.json({ status: 200, data: followers });
  } catch (error: unknown) {
    return NextResponse.json({
      status: 500,
      message: `Internal server error: ${error}`,
    });
  }
}
```

Can someone help me or tells me what i do wrong ?

Comment: Are you awaiting when you call this async function of yours?

Comment: yes i think so !

Comment: I don't know what to advise here, but why are you trying to use findUnique?  did you try using await prisma.user.findFirst instead?

Comment: You can chain all of your prisma requests into one (provided that your relations are setup correctly), no need to do it separately. i.e. on your first call just include followers then include user on the followers. You should also be using the res param instead of using NextResponse.

Comment: i'm using findUnique to find each user and their data that match the followers id i have retrieved before.